# MySQL weekly report with given start date and end date

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that store following data:

```
recordDate  itemID  price
2012-03-30  2       15.1
2012-03-30  13      15.1
2012-04-06  2       15.2
2012-04-06  13      15.3
2012-04-15  2       16.2
2012-04-16  13      16.3
2012-04-26  2       14.9
2012-04-26  13      15.0
...
```

I would like to have a weekly report that start from friday and end at next thursday.
And also the data selected is only recorded in the given date.

For example: `startDate = "2012-04-01", endDate = "2012-04-30"`

My expected result is like this:

```
weekStart   weekEnd     itemID   price
2012-04-06  2012-04-12  2        15.2
2012-04-06  2012-04-12  13       15.3
2012-04-13  2012-04-19  2        16.2
2012-04-13  2012-04-19  13       16.3
2012-04-20  2012-04-27  2        14.9
2012-04-20  2012-04-27  13       15.0
...
```

How can I get this result? I'm not familiar with SQL so I cannot figure how to write the statement.

Comment: I can get the friday and thursday dates from php, and get the result from one week, but I don't know how to group the result like I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  DAYNAME('2012-04-06') AS `start_week`,
  DAYNAME('2012-04-12') AS `End_week`,
  item_id,
  price 
FROM
  store 
WHERE record_date BETWEEN '2012-04-06' 
  AND '2012-04-12' ;
```

Try this ?

Comment: I think you meant to say group by item_id then here is your query

SELECT 
  DAYNAME('2012-04-06') AS `start_week`,
  DAYNAME('2012-04-12') AS `End_week`,
  item_id,
  price 
FROM
  store 
WHERE record_date BETWEEN '2012-04-06' 
  AND '2012-04-12' GROUP BY item_id;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from store where DAYNAME(recordDate) in ('Friday','Saturday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday') and 
start_date = '2012-01-01' and end_date = '2012-04-10'
```